# Extracting decimals from a number in Python

Tags: python, python-2.5

I am writing a function to extract decimals from a number. Ignore the exception and its syntax, I am working on 2.5.2 (default Leopard version). My function does not yet handle 0's. My issue is, the function produces random errors with certain numbers, and I don't understand the reason. I will post an error readout after the code.

---

Function:

```
def extractDecimals(num):
    try:
        if(num > int(num)):
            decimals = num - int(num)
            while(decimals > int(decimals)):
                print 'decimal: ' + str(decimals)
                print 'int: ' + str(int(decimals))
                decimals *= 10
            decimals = int(decimals)
            return decimals
        else:
            raise DecimalError(num)
    except DecimalError, e:
        e.printErrorMessage()
```

Exception Class:

```
class DecimalError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def printErrorMessage(self):
        print 'The number, ' + str(self.value) + ', is not a decimal.'
```

Here is error output when I input the number 1.988:
`decimal: 0.988

int: 0

decimal: 9.88

int: 9

decimal: 98.8

int: 98

decimal: 988.0

int: 987

decimal: 9880.0

int: 9879

decimal: 98800.0

int: 98799

decimal: 988000.0

int: 987999

decimal: 9880000.0

int: 9879999

decimal: 98800000.0

int: 98799999

decimal: 988000000.0

int: 987999999

decimal: 9880000000.0

int: 9879999999

decimal: 98800000000.0

int: 98799999999

decimal: 988000000000.0

int: 987999999999

decimal: 9.88e+12

int: 9879999999999

decimal: 9.88e+13

int: 98799999999999

decimal: 9.88e+14

int: 987999999999999

9879999999999998`

---

I do not know why this error is popping up. Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that (binary) floating point numbers aren't precisely representable as decimals.  See [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help, everyone. There are definitely better ways that I could have gone about doing this program, as you guys pointed out, but I am less interested in the result and more interested in what I learn along the way. That's part of the reason why I don't use all of the built in capabilities of Python. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

As Ned Batchelder said, not all decimals are exactly representable as floats. A float is represented by a certain number of binary digits which are used to approximate the decimal as closely as possible. You can never assume a float is exactly equal to a decimal.

```
In [49]: num
Out[49]: 1.988

In [50]: decimals=num - int(num)

In [51]: decimals
Out[51]: 0.98799999999999999

In [52]: print decimals   # Notice that print rounds the result, masking the inaccuracy.
0.988
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point for more info on the binary representation of floats.

There are other ways to achieve you goal. Here is one way, using string operations:

```
def extractDecimals(num):
    try:
        numstr=str(num)
        return int(numstr[numstr.find('.')+1:])
    except ValueError, e:
        print 'The number, %s is not a decimal.'%num
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, the issue you are seeing is due to the inexact representation of floating point numbers

Try your program with Python's `Decimal`

```
from decimal import Decimal
extractDecimals(Decimal("0.988"))
```

Comment: does `Decimal` have `extractDecimals`?

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, floating point numbers are not exactly equal to decimals. You can see this by using the modulus operator like so:

```
>>> 0.988 % 1
0.98799999999999999
>>> 9.88 % 1
0.88000000000000078
>>> 98.8 % 1
0.79999999999999716
```

This gives the remainder of division by 1, or the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in their answers, arithmetic with floats doesn't always result in what you expect due to rounding errors. In this case, perhaps converting the float into a string and back is better?

```
In [1]: num = 1.988

In [2]: num_str = str(num)

In [3]: decimal = num_str.split('.')[1]

In [4]: decimal = int(decimal)

In [5]: decimal
Out[5]: 988
```